# In Perl, what's the difference between "if defined $count" and "if $count"?

Tags: perl

I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $count = 0; 
my ( @first , @second , @third );

while ($count <= 7){

    push ( @first , $count);
    push ( @second , $count) if defined $count;
    push ( @third , $count) if $count;
    $count++;

}

print "first: @first\n";
print "second: @second\n";
print "third: @third\n";
```

This produces the following output:

```
first: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
second: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
third: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

What's the difference between putting `if defined $count` vs. `if $count`, other than the latter method won't add the zero to the array? I've searched the perldocs but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Truth and Falsehood in perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood) explains what values are considered false in a boolean context:

> The number 0, the strings `'0'` and `''`,
>   the empty list `()`, and `undef` are
>   all false in a boolean context.  All other values are true.

`undef` is the value of a variable that has never been initialized (or that has been reset using the [`undef` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html)).  The [`defined` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) returns true if the value of the expression is not `undef`.

`if $count` is false if `$count` is the number 0, the string `'0'`, the empty string, `undef`, or an object that has been [overloaded](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?overload) to return one of those things when used in a boolean context.  Otherwise, it's true.  (The empty list can't be stored in a scalar variable.)

`if defined $count` is false only if `$count` is `undef`.

Answer (score 5):

if you see the documentation of [defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) in perldoc then you will find that

- Returns a Boolean value telling
  whether EXPR has a value other
  than the undefined value undef. If EXPR is not present, $_ is
  checked.
- A simple **Boolean test will not
  distinguish among undef, zero, the
  empty string, and "0" , which are all
  equally false**.

that means,

```
push ( @second , 'undef') if defined $count;
```

when `$count = 0`, then it is defined because `0` is different from `undef` and **defined** returns true, but in this case `push ( @third , 'undef') if $count;` `if condition` fails, that's why it is not pushing 0 into the array.

Answer (score 3):

The `defined` predicate tests to see whether the variable (`$count` in this case) is defined at all. In the code you've written, it always will be defined inside the loop because it's always got some value.

If you were to add:

```
undef $count;
push ( @first , 'undef'); 
push ( @second , 'undef') if defined $count; 
push ( @third , 'undef') if $count;
```

after the loop, you would see the difference. (Note that I changed the code to add the literal `'undef'` instead of `$count` because you'll get misleading effects from adding the actual `undef` value.

Comment: It might be a bit more correct to say that defined() returns true or false andn that the if() checks that value. The defined() does the same thing with or without the conditional.

Answer (score 3):

The `if` decides to run its block (or single statement) by looking at the value of the expression you give it:

```
 if( EXPR ) { ... }
```

If that expression is true, it runs its block. If that expression is false, it doesn't.

That expression can be just about anything. Perl evaluates the expression, reducing it to a value that is either true or false. The `if()` then looks at that value.

So, removing that part of your question, you're left with "What's the difference between `defined $count` and `$count`". Well, one is the return value for [defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) and the other is whatever value is stored in `$count`.

When you want to figure out what a particular bit of code is doing, reduce it in the same logical process that `perl` would, one step at a time. See what each step does, and you'll often be able to answer your own questions. :)

You say that you searched the documentation, but I'm not sure where you looked. If you want to look up a built-in function, you can use perldoc's `-f` switch:

```
 $ perldoc -f defined
```

If you want to read about Perl's syntax for things such as `if`, that's in [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html).

I have a beginner's guide to the Perl docs in [Perl documentation documentation](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=408254).

Answer (score -1):

The way I read it.

`if $count` is only true when `$count` evaluates `!= 0`, hence the third array has no `0` in it.

`if defined $count` checks to see if the `$count` as a scalar has been created, and as you have `$count` scalar, it's the same as the first one.

Comment: should be: "when $count evaluates != 0"

Comment: They both work the same way, actually. It's the value that they test that is different. The first tests the value of $count, the second the value of defined $count. if() doesn't care how you get the value.